# Can't change the text in TextView of second activity on Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I'm trying to make an android application. It has two activities: MainActivity and Activity_Service. In MainActivity, there is a button "service" used to pass to Activity_Service. I want to send a string from MainActivity to Activity_Service and then display it in a textview. I would like to show you the codes.
Create the Intent in the MainActivity:

```
service.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String message = "bla bla bla";
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityService.class);
                intent.putExtra("message", message);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

And onCreate() method in the Activity_Service:

```
public class ActivityService extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String message = bundle.getString("message");
    System.out.println(message);
    //TextView txtView = new TextView(this); 
    TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtView.setText(message);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

The XML files created by Eclipse while creating the new activity (Activity_Service):
activity_service.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.alljoynandroid.ActivityService"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Fragment_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.alljoynandroid.ActivityService$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In onCreate() method of Activity_Service, if I use `TextView txtView = new TextView(this);`, It works: It can pass from MainActivity to Activity_Service, but then we can't setText. Other side, if I use `TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);`, it doesn't work all. Could you please help me to solve it? I was trying for 2 days and now I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this code part from your `Activity`

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

and change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity);
```

Comment: Oh, It works now. Thank you very much. Could you please explain to me why we have to remove: if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}. Sorry for this question bc I'm an Android beginner.

Comment: @VUONGTam Your textView coming from `Fragment_activity` layout and there is no textView found in your `activity_service` layout.